# PDO query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, mysqli, pdo

I have used a join query, it is working fine but taking very long time(30sec using mysql workbench).
How can i improve my execution time by re-writting the below query.
The query is as follows,

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getQueryBuilder();
            $queryBuilder
                ->select('count(*) as numberValidatedParts')
                ->from($this->tableName, 'p') // p for parts table
                ->innerJoin('p', 'cpk_catalog', 'cc', 'cc.part_id = p.part_id')
                ->innerJoin('p', 'images_catalog', 'ic', 'ic.sku_id = cc.sku_id')
                ->innerJoin('p', 'images', 'i', 'i.ImageId = ic.ImageId')
                ->where('i.IsValidated = 1')            
                ->andWhere('p.is_active = 1')            
                ->groupBy('cc.sku_id')
                ->having('numberValidatedParts = (
                    select count(*) as totalNumberOfParts
                    from images_catalog as ic
                    where ic.`sku_id`=cc.`sku_id`
                )');
            $sql = sprintf('select count(*) from (%s) as number', $queryBuilder->getSQL());
            return $this->doctrine->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: I can't figure out too much withouth having the SQL schema and the purpose of this query, but you can try to use an EXISTS instead of an INNER JOIN to validate the image and see if there are any improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I can see four possible reasons:

1. Check indexes and relations on all tables involved
2. "Having" is performed after the query which can make it slow
3. Using a subselect inside "having".
4. Using the entire query from the queryBuilder as a subquery to your "select count(*)" query

Comment: Dear Rikard,
The query is as follows 

" select count(*) from (SELECT count(*) as numberValidatedParts FROM parts p INNER JOIN cpk_catalog cc ON cc.part_id = p.part_id INNER JOIN images_catalog ic ON ic.sku_id = cc.sku_id INNER JOIN images i ON i.ImageId = ic.ImageId WHERE (i.IsValidated = 1) AND (p.is_active = 1) GROUP BY cc.sku_id HAVING numberValidatedParts = (
                select count(*) as totalNumberOfParts
                from images_catalog as ic
                where ic.`sku_id`=cc.`sku_id`
            )) as number "

Thank you for quick response

Comment: @bharathiraja Consider using the edit link under your question to update it with your query.  As you may have noticed, comments do not format well.

Comment: @bharathiraja as J.Almandos pointed out, it is hard to find the reason without the SQL-schema. One thing you can do is to run your query prefixed with EXPLAIN to see how the query uses indexes. Then you can use that information to optimize both your query and your table indexes.